# React Native AsyncStorage.getItem returning undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Disclaimer: Still learning RN, first time using AsyncStorage.

So I'm trying to store an array of "item" objects in AsyncStorage. A user can create "item" objects and they should eventually display in a FlatList (or similar component) on another screen.

Ex:

```
itemArray = [
{
    keywords: "box",
    size: "medium",
    color: "black",
},
{
    keywords: "pillow",
    size: "large",
    color: "white",
}]
```

When the user fills out text input boxes and hits add, I call a function, `addItem`, which retrieves the current `itemArray` from storage, and appends another `item` object with the values of the form. However, it seems that the `res` variable returned from the call is undefined.

The `storeData` function simply calls AsyncStorage.setItem().

Error I am getting: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
addItem = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('itemArray')
                .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
                .then(json => console.log(json));
            // Item array is populated, append to it
            if(res !== null) {
                console.log(res);    // Outputs undefined
                var itemArray = res.data;

                itemArray.push({"keywords": this.state.keywords, "color": this.state.color, "size": this.state.size});
                storeData(array);
            }
            // Item array is not populated, initialize and append
            else {
                console.log(res);    // Outputs undefined
                var itemArray = new Array();
                itemArray.push({"keywords": this.state.keywords, "color": this.state.color, "size": this.state.size});
                storeData(itemArray);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            // error reading value
            console.log(e);    // Outputs TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
        }
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the getItem function?

**Edit:** Here is my storeData function, as it may be the source of the error:

```
storeData = async (itemArray) => {
        try {
            var itemData = {
                data: itemArray,
            };
            console.log(itemData);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('itemArray', JSON.stringify(itemData))
            console.log('success!');
        } catch (e) {
            // saving error
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the 'then' function if you use 'await'.

Instead:

```
const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('itemArray')
.then(req => JSON.parse(req))
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Do This:

```
const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('itemArray');
const parsed = JSON.parse(res);
```

Now you can use the 'parsed' variable to access the data inside:

```
console.log(parsed.data); // should get you your data...
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks! I implemented this solution. However, parsed is still undefined when I console.log(parsed.data).

Comment: Can you show me the code of the store Data() function?

Comment: Yes, it's been added to the original post!

Answer (score 0):

You either use `Async - wait` syntax ... or `then ... catch` ... you can't use them both

```
addItem = async () => {
  const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('itemArray');

  // do something with your res
  const resArr = JSON.parse(res);
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight! However, resArr is still undefined when I console.log(resArr).

Comment: console log `res` const ... if it's undefined ... you're most likely haven't set the item correctly